# Weird graphics in matplotlib when changing the scale

Tags: matplotlib

I get a histogram picture in matplotlib which looks great. Now I realize I need a log scale on the y-axis, so I just add to the code:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

but then, the histogram bars dissapear and I only get some sparse points, do you know waht could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use hist's `log=True` keyword argument instead. This is a FAQ in matplotlib-user list :)